# How can I change cursor shape & size?

Tags: unity-game-engine, cursor

Can anyone help me.
I am new in unity.
I just want to try change cursor shape & size using something similar to this code:

```
Cursor.SetCursor(Texture2D,CursorMode)
```

but this is not working.

Comment: read this: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/145024/unity3d-custom-cursors.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@kajal Go to File -> Player Settings -> Default Settings ->Set Your texture here to change the cursor and its Hotspot to change the cursor size.

Comment: Thanks @Renuka Devganiya,It is very easy way to set custom cursor.
[kajal](http://www.variyasoftsolutions.com/unity3d.html).

Comment: The hotspot is not the cursor size but the location of the cursor icon where the click is executed. Hotspot of (0,0) means the click is pressed at the top left corner of the cusror texture. See this: https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UIElements.Cursor-hotspot.html